# Can you call the stuffing you put in Turkey "filling"?

Tags: language, thanksgiving

They seem a bit similar to me, but a lot of people argue that the answer is "stuffing" and that you can't call it "filling".

Comment: There's probably a way to ask this that's a bit less poll-ish, but as-is I don't think we want to encourage additional answers.

Answer (score 4):

I am from Eastern Pennsylvania, where we call it "Filling".
Good luck convincing the rest of the world, though. I catch crap for it all the time.

Filling, Stuffing, Dressing....It's all the same, regional dialects aside.

Comment: Exactly. Who the hell calls that filling?? Hmmm...You, I guess.

Comment: sounds like a regional thing ... it's not in the [2003 Harvard Dialect Survey](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~jakatz2/project-dialect.html), though.  ([current survey](http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/))

Comment: FWIW, I've only ever heard the terms "dressing" and "stuffing" (my preferred term) but see no reason why "filling" wouldn't be just as logical. Just might have to explain yourself more often.